# Email plugin connection refused

Tags: logstash

I currently try to use the email plugin of Logstash. The instance of Logstash however always crashes with a ECONNREFUSED error.

This is the content of my config.conf file:

```
input {
    generator {
        lines => [ "logstash test: line 1" ]
        count => 1
    }
}
output {
    email { 
        to => "stuff@stuff.com" 
    } 
}
```

It always fails with the following error:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused initialize at org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:126           open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1178      tcp_socket at file:/opt/logstash/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/smtp.rb:540        do_start at file:/opt/logstash/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META -INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/smtp.rb:549         timeout at org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:126        do_start at file:/opt/logstash/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META -INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/smtp.rb:549           start at file:/opt/logstash/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META -INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/net/smtp.rb:519        deliver! at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mai l/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:136        deliver! at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mail-2.5.3/lib/mail/message.rb:245        receive at /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/email.rb:251         handle at /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:86     initialize at (eval):17           call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271         output at /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:266   outputworker at /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:225  start_outputs at /opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152

Comment: You're using the default settings (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html#plugins-outputs-email-options) so Logstash is attempting to connect to the SMTP server at localhost:25, but nobody is answering.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the [default settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html#plugins-outputs-email-options), so Logstash is attempting to connect to the SMTP server at localhost:25, but no server is listening at that address.

Thanks Magnus Bäck for pointing that out in the comments.